# My activity is not starting

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

My problem is the following:
I've got one activity (MainActivity) which, inside it, show a fragment (MainFragment). In the MainFragment, there is a FloatingActionButton which call a new activity (NewStudentActivity). The problem is, I click the FAB, and nothing happens! What is weird is that, in the memory monitor, if I keep pressing the FAB, it keeps going up, as if the activity is created but never shown. Here's the codes for MainFragment and NewStudentActivity:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private View fragmentView;

private FloatingActionButton fab;
private ListView listView;
private StudentAdapter listViewAdapter;

private ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

public static MainFragment newInstance() {
    return new MainFragment();
}

public MainFragment(){
    //Required empty constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){

    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NewStudentActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_students);

    listViewAdapter = new StudentAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), studentList);
    prepareStudentData(getStudents());
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);



    return fragmentView;
}

//-----------------NewStudentActivity---------------------


public class NewStudentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CalcMethodFragment.SelectCalcOptionDialogListener,
    UserGenderFragment.SelectGenderOptionDialogListener{

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int calcMethod;
private int userGender;

public interface StudentCreatedListener{
    void onStudentCreated();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_student);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    CalcMethodFragment frag = new CalcMethodFragment();
    frag.show(ft, "calc_method");
}
```

And yes, all of the activities are declared in the manifest.

As some of you guys asked, here is the CalcMethodFragment code (it is just a DialogFragment):

```
public class CalcMethodFragment extends DialogFragment{

private int selectedOption;

public CalcMethodFragment(){

}

public interface SelectCalcOptionDialogListener{
    void onCalcFinishEditDialog(int selectedOption);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    final SelectCalcOptionDialogListener activity = (SelectCalcOptionDialogListener) getActivity();

    CharSequence[] options = {
            "Petroski, 1995",
            "Guedes, 1985"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Escolha o método de cálculo").setSingleChoiceItems(options, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            selectedOption = i;
        }
    }).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            activity.onCalcFinishEditDialog(selectedOption);
        }
    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            selectedOption = 42;
            activity.onCalcFinishEditDialog(selectedOption);
            dismiss();
        }
    });



    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Can you put a break point on the onCreate method and see if it's getting called?

Comment: Just did that, and it confirms my theory that the NewStudentActivity is being called but never shown T-T

Comment: put  a debug inside fab onClick and check if its  onclick is called

Comment: Yes, it is called when I press the FAB

Comment: Is `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` totally necessary, can you try without it?

Comment: Yes, I can try without it, I just put it there to help with proper back navigation.

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque didn't work.

Comment: Can we see the CalcMethodFragment class ?

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque there it is.

Comment: as you are saying your FAB is not working, so you can put ```Log.d("debug","working");``` code inside FAb click listener and check in android monitor whether it's working or not. if it's working then first remove that flag and after use this ```getActivity().startActivity(i)``` .

Comment: @AbdulRizwan actually, I tested it out and the FAB is working, also the activity onCreate method is called, the problem is that nothing is shown from the NewStudentActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a FragmentTransaction show can you try this:

```
CalcMethodFragment dialog = new CalcMethodFragment ();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "calc_method");
```

Comment: Nothing happened T-T

Comment: if you put log.d(...) in your Dialog's `onCreateDialog` do they get called?

try puting one in the first line and in the last one, before returning.

Comment: Actually, it did called the log.d's on the first and last line, so it just skipped all the other things between then? Weird...

Comment: We are closer to solving this!, its not that it just skipped them, as you're initializing the fragment there would be no interaction there. the `dialog.show` should make that happen

Comment: could you try to show the dialog without  the viewPager and the tabLayout? maybe something is happening that will not let the dialog show, could you try that to narrow the problems?

Comment: IT WORKED, OMG, thanks man. So, the problem is that the layout is being created and overriding the dialog?

Comment: When I took out the viewPager only, it worked. I guess I understood now the problem, it's within the depths of this app hahah thank you dude

Comment: Glad to have helped you to troubleshoot this problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try change
`Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NewStudentActivity.class);`

to
`Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), NewStudentActivity.class);
getContext().startActivity(i);`

It would help to see your `CalcMethodFrag#show()` method

Comment: Didn't work. Also, getContext() requires API level 23, and I need my app to work from 21. But thanks anyway.

Comment: i suspect the problem is your fragment loading mechanism...can you post that code?